# Does reaching MaxClients interfere with vhosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server

I'm running a MacOS Xserve using a Tenon apache/php build. I've noticed that once maxclients is reached, I start getting errors like 'Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /Library/Tenon/WebServer/Documents/'

Our server hosts 100+ websites and each are configured using their own vhost file, but Tenon has a default 'DocumentRoot /Library/Tenon/WebServer/Documents'.

Would reaching maxclients interfere with being able to properly parse vhosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out why this was happening. See [Proper way to disable Apache listening on localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/211382/proper-way-to-disable-apache-listening-on-localhost) for an explanation and further question